# Windows 10 Slow Boot Times Pre BIOS, Help Understanding Boot Trace

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios

I currently have exceedingly long pre-BIOS boot times, taking on average around 75 seconds:
[image]

I have tried in my BIOS enabling and disabling fast boot, as well as unplugging all USBs and Drives that are not my SSD that I boot off of. I have also disabled all start up programs and non Microsoft services. I have also made a boot trace but am having trouble using the performance analyser to figure out what is wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Link to ETL file generated froom boot trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SlwiVzRSI7Maq8fLBXp6WTqNka4HtwKn/view?usp=sharing

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
RAM: 2x8GB 3200 mhz corsair
Motherboard: ASUS Prime B550M-K
Graphics Card: NVidia GTX 1050ti 4GB VRAM
SSD: 476GB ADATA SX8200PNP
BIOS Version/Date : American Megatrends Inc. 0805, 01/07/2020
```

Comment: What are your computer model and BIOS version? Is the BIOS the latest version?

Comment: CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
RAM: 2x8GB 3200 mhz corsair 
Motherboard: ASUS Prime B550M-K
Graphics Card: NVidia GTX 1050ti 4GB VRAM
SSD: 476GB ADATA SX8200PNP

BIOS Version: BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 0805, 01/07/2020

Comment: [BIOS Version 2803](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-B550M-K/HelpDesk_BIOS/) from 2022/05/23 is available. Try it first.

Comment: I honestly mean no offense in telling you these things but first of all.. [there is no BIOS](https://www.howtogeek.com/56958/htg-explains-how-uefi-will-replace-the-bios/).  It is UEFI firmware.  Second of all, whatever you screenshot or talk about dealing with windows has nothing to do with "pre bios". Windows doesn't come into the game until the UEFI code points at a windows partition and says "GO!, GO!, GO!"

Answer (score 1):

If you go directly to BIOS, not booting to OS, does the issue persist? Then it appears to be an issue with BIOS/UEFI enumerating bootable devices. You've performed some good diagnosis, unplugging USB devices *not* involved in the boot process, so that leaves booting from the SSD itself as the last possibility.

To verify that issue, use a small (between 4 and 32 GB) flash USB drive, FAT32 formatted, to make a bootable (live) OS, such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) or the even faster-loading [Knoppix](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/make-a-knoppix-usb-flash-drive-in-windows/). If you can go to BIOS setup quickly, and can boot the alternate OS much faster than  the external SSD, then the issue is due to the interaction of BIOS and that SSD.

- Be sure the SSD is set as the *first* item in boot order.
- Disable [at least temporarily, to test] other boot devices, if possible, such as booting from the network and all internal drives.

It also might be that another type of SSD would boot faster in your system, though hat would be more trouble to test.